# Using html timepicker with interval

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to use html time picker with a certain interval

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Link shows that step is supported, however I tried latest Chrome/Edge/Firefox and it doesn't seem to work

```
 <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" step="300">
```

Can someone please confirm if its still supported?

[image]

Comment: If you scroll in the Mozilla page where it talks about `step` in detail, I quote "This property has some strange effects across browsers, so is not completely reliable." So just Google some JavaScript time picker and get on with life.

Answer (score 0):

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/forms/time-picker1/

Use the above time pickers,the UI will be shown consistent in all different browsers platforms and have full customized controls options available,default time picker or date picker have different ui behaviour in different browser and os platforms.

Comment: Its not free :(

Comment: @bluepiranha Stack Overflow is not a shopping site or a freeware directory. Answers which suggest using a library are fine, but as an asker, you are limited in how you can guide the recommendations, because asking for them is off-topic. If you have clear requirements, you might check the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) of [softwarerecs.se] to see if your recommendation request can be made on topic there.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the HTML time input doesn't support step by itself anymore.
[Here's a w3schools article that explains how to apply step with JavaScript instead.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_input_time_step.asp)

Comment: Please don't post links to articles explaining the answer. Instead, if you can, paraphrase the answer (without plagiarizing) the article and give reference to the author and publisher of the article.

Comment: I can find no documentation that the `step` attribute is deprecated or is no longer supported. Please back up such statements with proof of some kind.